# React-native-camera - TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-camera

I am trying to use the camera for a rect native app using 'react-native-camera'.
I keep getting the following error when I'm trying to navigate to the camera screen.

Here's my code:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView,StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,TextInput,View,Text,StatusBar,Image} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import UserMainScreen from './UserMainScreen.js';
import Camera from 'react-native-camera';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';

class CameraScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={cam_styles.container}>
                <Camera ref={cam=>{this.camera = cam;}} style={cam_styles.preview} aspect = {Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                        <Text style={cam_styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
                    </Camera>
            </View>
        );
    }

    takePicture(){
        const options ={};
        this.camera.capture({metadata: options})
        .then(data=>console.log(data))
        .catch(error=>console.log(error));
    }
}

const cam_styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    preview:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    capture:{
        flex:0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        color:'#000',
        padding:10,
        margin:40
    }
});

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: UserMainScreen,
    Login : LoginScreen,
    Camera : CameraScreen,
},
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: 'none',
    }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

class Login extends Component{

    render (){      
        return (
                <AppContainer />   
        );
    }
}
export default Login;
```

This is the error I keep getting.I tried removing the aspect attribute but I get a `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or class/function but got undefined. Check the render method of CameraScreen`

With my current code this is the error log I get. How do I solve this?

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeCamera.Camera.constants')

This error is located at:
    in CameraScreen (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:900)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:71)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.tsx:93)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.tsx:95)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.tsx:975)
    in RCTView (at screens.native.js:101)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.tsx:384)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.tsx:374)
    in PanGestureHandler (at StackViewLayout.tsx:367)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:104)
    in RCTView (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:41)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:80)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:430)
    in NavigationContainer (at Login.js:97)
    in Login
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:101)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

CameraScreen#render
    Login.js:42:100
renderRoot
    [native code]:0
runRootCallback
    [native code]:0
unstable_runWithPriority
    scheduler.development.js:643:23
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using expo comment out your `import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';`and use `import { Camera } from 'expo';`  If you're not using expo then do the opposite.

Render the expo way:

```js
import { Camera } from 'expo';
class CameraScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={cam_styles.container}>
                <Camera ref={cam=>{this.camera = cam;}} style={cam_styles.preview} aspect = {Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                        <Text style={cam_styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
                    </Camera>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Render the **non** expo way:

```js
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';
class CameraScreen extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={cam_styles.container}>
                <RNCamera ref={cam=>{this.camera = cam;}} style={cam_styles.preview} aspect = {Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
                        <Text style={cam_styles.capture} onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>[CAPTURE]</Text>
                    </RNCamera>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing the module like `import {RNCamera as Camera} from 'react-native-camera'` and the constants should be accessed like `Camera.Constants`

Example:

```
import { RNCamera as Camera } from "react-native-camera"

const CameraComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera
        ref={ref => {
          camRef = ref
        }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        aspect={Camera.Constants.Aspect.fill}
        flashMode={Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
        type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}>
        <Text
          style={{ position: "absolute", alignSelf: "baseline" }}
          onPress={() => {takePicture(camRef)}}>CAPTURE</Text>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please provide code with your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Hi @ethry I've updated my answer with an example snippet.

Comment: Please remove "Hope this helps" and "Thanks" from your post since I cannot edit it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021

Comment: I've removed please check @ethry